# Getting messageID from email in Outlook VBA 2003

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

Is there a easy way to get the current shown (preferably selected) message-ID via VBA ?
**without** having to buy Redemption or some other package..

I need to message ID so I can make a link to a web-application that reads the mail and does some other stuff with it

Can't seem to use MAPI or PropertyAccessor in outlook 2003..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the unique ID for the message? Try the EntryID Property:

```
ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).EntryID
```

FYI PropertyAccessor was added in Outlook 2007, you wouldn't see it in 2003.