# VotingOptions Response Reply with Custom Body

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a macro that runs when I accept specific emails. It replies to the email with a voting option of either "Approved" or "Rejected".

When the recipient of the voting option responds with their choice, the received "choice" email does not have a body. Is there a way to retain the body?

I've tried this so far:

```vb
With objMsg
    .To = strEmail
    .HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody
    .Subject = "Is This Approved?"
    .VotingOptions = "Approved;Rejected"
    .VotingResponse = "Yes"
    .Attachments.Add Item
    .Display
    .Send
End With
```

I believe this is only affecting the initial email and not the responses.

I looked at the [MailItem Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx), but didn't see any options for Voting outside of `.VotingOptions` and `.VotingResponse`.

I would be open to ideas outside of Voting buttons (such as a Task or something like that) as long as it can include the body in the response.

Comment: The body of the reply is dependent on the recipient and whether they edit the reply before sending. Therefore you have two options that I can see. Either the recipients will each require a VBA backend to alter the message to return to you (unlikely to be achievable) or you can add a hash code of sorts (or date-time) to the subject so that you can know which e-mail it refers to when the vote is received

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710191/getting-messageid-from-email-in-outlook-vba-2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, I think adding a small hash to the subject is the only way you can track message thread replies. Below is some code for generating a hash based on the date and time to add as a prefix to the subject

```
Sub TestHash()
    Dim lDate As Date: lDate = Now
    MsgBox DateTimeHash(lDate)
End Sub

Function DateTimeHash(lDate As Date) As String
    DateTimeHash = "#" & fBase36Encode(DateValue(lDate)) & _
    fBase36Encode(60 * (60 * Hour(lDate) + Minute(lDate)) + Second(lDate)) & "#"
End Function

Function fBase36Encode(ByRef lngNumToConvert As Long) As String
    'Will Convert any Positive Integer to a Base36 String
    fBase36Encode = "0"
    If lngNumToConvert = 0 Then Exit Function

    Dim strAlphabet As String: strAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    fBase36Encode = vbNullString
    Do While lngNumToConvert <> 0
        fBase36Encode = Mid(strAlphabet, lngNumToConvert Mod 36 + 1, 1) & fBase36Encode
        lngNumToConvert = lngNumToConvert \ 36
    Loop
End Function
```

*** EDIT ***

Using a reversible base 64 hash instead:

```
Sub TestHash()
    Dim lDate As Date: lDate = Now
    Debug.Print DateTimeHash(lDate)
    Debug.Print DateTimeUnhash(DateTimeHash(lDate))
End Sub

Function DateTimeHash(ByRef lDate As Date) As String
    Dim Secs As String: Secs = Encode64(60 * (60 * Hour(lDate) + Minute(lDate)) + Second(lDate))
    DateTimeHash = "#" & Encode64(DateValue(lDate)) & String(3 - Len(Secs), "0") & Secs & "#"
End Function

Function DateTimeUnhash(ByRef Hash As String) As Date
    Hash = Replace(Hash, "#", "")
    Dim Days As Long: Days = Decode64(Left(Hash, Len(Hash) - 3))
    Dim Secs As Long: Secs = Decode64(Right(Hash, 3))
    DateTimeUnhash = DateAdd("d", Days, "0") + DateAdd("s", Secs, "0")
End Function

Function Encode64(ByRef Value As Long) As String
    'Will Convert any Positive Integer to a Base64 String
    Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

    Encode64 = IIf(Value > 0, vbNullString, "0")
    If Encode64 = "0" Then Exit Function
    Do While Value <> 0
        Encode64 = Mid(Base64, Value Mod 64 + 1, 1) & Encode64
        Value = Value \ 64
    Loop
End Function

Function Decode64(ByRef Value As String) As Long
    'Will Convert any Base64 String to a Positive Integer
    Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

    Decode64 = IIf(Value = "", -1, 0)
    Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To Len(Value)
        If Decode64 = -1 Then Exit Function ' Error detected with Value string
        Decode64 = Decode64 * 64
        Decode64 = IIf(InStr(Base64, Mid(Value, i, 1)) > 0, _
            Decode64 + InStr(Base64, Mid(Value, i, 1)) - 1, -1)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Very inventive. In fact, so inventive, that I ended up doing that very thing to solve the issue. I wanted to keep the question open to see if there were any other alternatives or ideas that others may have for me. However, great idea, because that is exactly what I used to get around this!

Comment: The extension to this is that if the hash is reversible, you could set up a newmail event to check for the hash, search sent items for the original e-mail (based on the hash time stamp) then copy the sent e-mail body into the reply body. Therefore actually completing what the remit of the original question was.

Comment: I agree. This wholely fulfills the requirements of the question, and it can be used to get around the issue at hand. I'm going to keep the question open until the end of the week, in hopes that someone comes along with a way to truly pass the information in the body. It seems like such a simple issue to solve, yet there is no direct way to solve it. Typical Microsoft.