# Generating 4 digits Unique ID from Date-Time in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA and I want to create 4 characters unique alphanumeric for order ID. I already used 0001 up to 9000, very soon will reach 9999. So I'm thinking of if there is a way to generate 4 alphanumeric from system date time (date-time-second). Already do the same thing using BASE 16 for 12 characters, but don't know if it can do for only 4 characters.

Any suggestions are appreciated

I am expecting to have unique ID 4 characters based on system date/time or any other method

Comment: You can't do what you're asking using only 4 characters from a date/time. The best you could do is convert to alphanumeric, where you would have `A001` through `A999`, then `B001` through `B999`, etc. Otherwise, you're going to need to expand to more than 4 characters. If you had thought ahead when designing your system, you would have realized that only 4 characters wouldn't work for very long. You should have used 6 or 8 (or more) from the start and left-padded with 0, as in `00000001`; this would give you a max of `99999999`, which should last for decades.

Comment: if you're going to the trouble of alphanumeric but with the unnecessary complexity of translating from date time, then why not _just_ alphanumeric, like Ken White says?

Comment: Currently I am storing the last number in an excel sheet, this method is vulnerable if user accidentally change it the number will be out of sequence. So, if possible I am finding a way to generate it without storing any  value in Excel

Comment: Does only a user use the generated numbers, or many?

Comment: There is a six digit date-time reversible hash [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872771/votingoptions-response-reply-with-custom-body/41024891#41024891) which may be editable to 4 digits

Comment: @FaneDuru This VBA only used by single user

Comment: Then, you can keep track of the last number writing it in Registry. It can be reed and rewritten after the last generation. And about the four digits generation, if it is necessary to be composed of only 4 digits, you can follow the suggestion in the first comment. So, you can try a pattern starting from `A` letter, followed by number of three digits and an algorithm able to jump at `B001` after `A999` and so on. Even `AA01` - `AA99` and so on until it will reach `ZZZZ`. Such an algorithm will increase the number of possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next function. It will increment your existing IDs up to "9999" and then it will create IDs adding letters starting from the first digit (first time) and from the last one when it reaches "ZZZZ":

```
Function CreateUniqueID(strCurrent As String) As String
   Dim nO As String, strL As String, vers As Long
   If Asc(left(strCurrent, 1)) < Asc(Right(strCurrent, 1)) Then vers = 1 'for the case of letter to the right
   nO = extrNumb(strCurrent)
   If Len(nO) = 4 Then 'process the existing IDs range ______________________
        If CLng(nO) < 9999 Then
            CreateUniqueID = Format(CLng(strCurrent) + 1, "0000"): Exit Function
        ElseIf nO = "9999" Then
            CreateUniqueID = "A001": Exit Function
        End If
   End If '__________________________________________________________
   
   'creates new IDs:
   If nO <> "" Then
     If vers = 1 Then 'the case of letter to the right
        strL = Right(strCurrent, Len(strCurrent) - Len(nO))
     Else                 ''the case of letter to the left
        strL = left(strCurrent, Len(strCurrent) - Len(nO))
     End If
        If CLng(nO) < CLng(String(Len(nO), "9")) Then
             nO = Format(CLng(nO) + 1, String(Len(nO), "0"))
        Else
          If vers = 1 Then
                If Asc(left(strL, 1)) < Asc("Z") Then
                   strL = IIf(Len(strL) = 1, Chr(Asc(strL) + 1), Chr(Asc(left(strL, 1)) + 1)) & Right(strL, Len(strL) - 1)
                   nO = Format(0, String(Len(nO), "0"))
                Else
                   strL = "A" & strL
                   nO = IIf(Len(strL) = 4, "", Format(0, String(Len(strCurrent) - Len(strL), "0")))
                End If
          Else
               If Asc(Right(strL, 1)) < Asc("Z") Then
                    strL = IIf(Len(strL) = 1, Chr(Asc(strL) + 1), left(strL, Len(strL) - 1) & Chr(Asc(Right(strL, 1)) + 1))
                    nO = Format(0, String(Len(nO), "0"))
                Else
                    strL = strL & "A"
                    nO = IIf(Len(strL) = 4, "", Format(0, String(Len(strCurrent) - Len(strL), "0")))
                End If
          End If
        End If
    Else
        If vers = 1 Then
             If Asc(left(strCurrent, 1)) < Asc("Y") Then
                strL = Chr(Asc(left(strCurrent, 1)) + 1) & Right(strCurrent, 3)
                nO = ""
            Else
                strL = "": nO = ""
                MsgBox "The increment limit has been reached (" & strCurrent & ")..."
            End If
        Else
            If Asc(Right(strCurrent, 1)) < Asc("Z") Then
                strL = left(strCurrent, 3) & Chr(Asc(Right(strCurrent, 1)) + 1)
                nO = ""
            Else
                strL = "A": nO = "000"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    CreateUniqueID = IIf(vers = 1, nO & strL, strL & nO)
End Function

Private Function extrNumb(strVal As String) As String
    With CreateObject("Vbscript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d{1,4})"
        .Global = True
        If .test(strVal) Then
            extrNumb = CStr(.Execute(strVal)(0))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

It will generate other new `26 * 1000 + 26 * 100 + 26 * 10 + 26 = 28886 + 28885 = 57772' new IDs (besides, 9999).

You can test the above function using something like:

```
Sub testCreateUniqueID()
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("0025") '0026 'existing pattern
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("9999") 'A000
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("A000") 'A001
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("A099") 'A100
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("A999") 'B000
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("P999") 'Q000
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("Z999") 'ZA00
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZA00") 'ZA01
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZA99") 'ZB00
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZB03") 'ZB04
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZB99") 'ZC00
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZ70") 'ZZ71
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZ99") 'ZZA0
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZA0") 'ZZA1
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZA9") 'ZZB0
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZZ1") 'ZZZ2
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZZ9") 'ZZZA
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZZB") 'ZZZC
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZZY") 'ZZZZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("ZZZZ") 'A000
   
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("A000") 'A001
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("001A") '002A
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("999A") '000B
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("000B") '001B
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("999Z") '00AZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("00AZ") '01AZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("99AZ") '00BZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("99ZZ") '0AZZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("9AZZ") '0BZZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("9ZZZ") 'AZZZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("DZZZ") 'EZZZ
   'Debug.Print CreateUniqueID("YZZZ") 'End
End Sub
```

Uncomment one row at a time and see the returned generated ID. Choose any ID you like to be tested.

You can save the IDs (the last one to be a reference for the next) in Registry using a code like the next one:

```
Sub GenerateGetSetSettingsRegistry()
    Const MyApp As String = "ExcelApplication"
    Const Sett As String = "Settings"
    Const IDVal As String = "ID"
    Dim existingID As String, newID As String
    
    existingID = GetSetting(MyApp, Sett, IDVal, "No value")     'read the Registry
    If existingID = "No value" Then                                     'if nothing in Registry:
        existingID = InputBox("No any ID entry in Registry." & vbCrLf & _
                                      "Please, enter the last generated ID:", "Enter the last ID")
        'If pressing Cancel, OK for no entry or Tot Right corner X:
        If existingID = "" Then MsgBox "You need to enter the last generated ID!", vbInformation, _
                                        "No any ID entered...": Exit Sub
        'If not 4 digits entered:
        If Len(existingID) <> 4 Then MsgBox "Entered ID must contain 4 digits!": Exit Sub
    End If
      'use the generated ID as you want
      '.........................................................
      'Save it in Registry:
    newID = CreateUniqueID(UCase(existingID)) 'using Ucase allowes inputing low case letters...
    SaveSetting MyApp, Sett, IDVal, newID
End Sub
```

Separate of that some other IDs can be created using another more complex algorithm, to process strings with numbers on both sides or in between (0A00, 1ZA0, 0ZZ9, 0A0A, 0Z0Z)...

I would like to receive some feedback after trying it...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `CreateUniqueID` Function it has one small flaw. As it is if you insert a number, it will work fine up to `0009`, but once it needs to change do `0010` It will give an error due to `strcurrent = ""`, since it will take the number as string, but will not change the format to `0000`.

Therefore I made a small adjustment to the code the solved this issue.

```
Function CreateUniqueID(strinput As Variant) As String

   Dim nO As String, strL As String, vers As Long
   Dim strcurrent as String

   strcurrent = format(CStr(strinput, "0000")

(...)
```

And this little change did the job. Now it takes all inputs from letters to numbers without running into any kind or error.

Thanks for creator of the function. It has been really helpful.